# Trouble Hosting Grafana Under Subpath in Kubernetes with Traefik Ingress (Azure, Helm, ArgoCD)

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, azure-aks, traefik-ingress

I'm attempting to host Grafana under a subpath in my Kubernetes cluster deployed via the Azure portal. I've used Helm to install Grafana and am managing the deployment with ArgoCD.

I want to access Grafana at http://my-domain.com/grafana/, and I've configured the root_url in Grafana's configmap to `root_url = http://your-domain.com/grafana/.` I have also set `subpath = true`

However, I'm having trouble with getting Traefik to route traffic to the correct subpath

When i enter the url your-domain.com/grafana Im redirected to your-domain.com/grafana/login instead. And give me the error "The page isnt redirecting properly".

I've tried modifying the IngressRoute and Traefik settings, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if there's a mistake in my configuration.

How should I configure my Traefik Ingress to route traffic to Grafana under the /grafana/ subpath in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster?
Are there any specific annotations or settings I should be using in my IngressRoute for this scenario?
What adjustments should I make to my Grafana configmap configuration to ensure it works correctly under a subpath?
Any guidance or suggestions on how to set up Grafana under a subpath with Traefik Ingress in Kubernetes, especially when using Helm and ArgoCD (UI) in the Azure portal, would be greatly appreciated.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingressroute
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`your-domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/grafana`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: prometheus-grafana
          port: 80
```

[ConfigMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bdIM.png)

Worth noting, I´ve tried hosting grafana on your-domain.com (without prefixes) and that works fine.
I´ve also tried hosting a different application on "your-domain.com/whoami" which doesn´t use any redirects and that works.
Also tried adding a grafana-middleware which didn´t help.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: grafana-path-prefix
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - "/grafana"
```